# Trouble importing aspose.words on python : (KeyError: 'aspose.words')

Tags: python, import, aspose.words

for some context : I have a secure pc (work one, no access to the internet) and a non-secure one. I made a simple app to use aspose.words on the non-secure, and it worked perfectly, just needed to install the library with pip and voilà.

After that, I installed the library on my secure pc with pip install --no-index --find-links link/to/library, however, I'm not able to import aspose.words anymore, only aspose. I get this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "converter.py", line 1, in <module>
    import aspose.words as aw
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 668, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 640, in _load_backward_compatible
KeyError: 'aspose.words'
```

I have an empty init file in the folder containing the converter.py app, so that shouldn't be a problem. But I don't get why it doesn't recognize aspose.words. And I'm sure it is downloaded, since pip show aspose-words works

Answer (score 2):

Its seems that `aspose-words` installation is broken and package folder `{PYTHON}/Lib/site-packages/aspose/` contains only `__init__.py` file. `aspose-words` package is a Python binary extensions and contains many `*.pyd` and `*.dll` files needed to work.

If you are using `PyInstaller` please use options `--collect-binaries` and `--collect-submodules` for `aspose` package. For example:

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --console --collect-binaries "aspose" --collect-submodules "aspose" path/to/script
```

Answer (score 0):

Install aspose words by:

```
pip install aspose-words
```